# How much sunlight do amaranth seedlings need?

Tags: seedlings, sunlight

I have some red amaranth seedlings getting 3 hrs of direct sunlight. They have 2~3 very small true leaves.[image] Should it be increased gradually or is it fine? The other place where I can put it has 7~8 hours of direct sun. Temperatures touching 41 deg celsius everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amaranth will appreciate full sun. I would increase gradually, maybe add an hour per day. These also look like they might be ready for a larger container.